# How can I use group by function with below query?

Tags: sql, group-by

**How can I use group by function with below query?**

Actually I tried to join (inner join) two tables With 2 fields.

**This is Ok:**

```
t1.fiels6 = t2.field7
```

**This doesn't work in inner join function. therefore I used it in where function:**

```
t1.field8 = SUBSTRING(t2.field9,1,INSTR(t2.field9,'-') - 1) 
and (INSTR(t2.field9,'-') - 1) < 14 
and (INSTR(t2.field9,'-') - 1) > 0
```

My main aim is to get the avg((t1.field3 * t2.field4)) and stddev((t1.field3 * t2.field4)) for every group of t2.field2

```
select 
    t1.field1 as f1, t2.field2 as f2,(t1.field3 * t2.field4) as f5 
from 
    pub.table1 t1, pub.table2 t2 
where 
    t1.fiels6 = t2.field7 
    and t1.field6 = 'XXX' 
    and t1.field8 = SUBSTRING(t2.field9,1,INSTR(t2.field9,'-') - 1) 
    and (INSTR(t2.field9,'-') - 1) < 14 and (INSTR(t2.field9,'-') - 1) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Move what you have to an inner select and group by --

```
select f2, avg(calced), atddev(calced)
from
(
  select 
    t1.field1 as f1, 
    t2.field2 as f2,
    (t1.field3 * t2.field4) as calced 
  from pub.table1 t1
  join pub.table2 t2 on t1.fiels6 = t2.field7 
                    and (INSTR(t2.field9,'-') - 1) < 14 
                    and (INSTR(t2.field9,'-') - 1) > 0
                    and t1.field8 = SUBSTRING(t2.field9,1,INSTR(t2.field9,'-') - 1) 
  where t1.field6 = 'XXX' 
) t
group by f2
```